# Use external associated file to pass arguments to my application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a clickonce enabled C# WinForms application for which I created a file association.
How would I be able to use an external file (associated to my application) to pass arguments to my application? I would like to, with the link, have the application open up a specific form, that exists in the main application.

And also prevent it from opening a new instance if the application is already running?

Comment: By external file, do you mean something along arguments passed in commandline? Like: `yourprogram.exe -admin -noUI -someOrder`

Comment: [This article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) might help with the second part of your question.

Comment: perhaps, `App.config` file is all you need?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear in my question. An example of what I need would be: An Assets Management application. When a new Computer is bought it goes through a purchase order process (already done). Once that is complete, an email would be sent to IT to complete the assignment of the computer. What I would like to achieve is to send the email with an attachment, when the IT guy opens the attachment, it should run the asset management app and open the computer details form.  AND there is my problem, I do not know how to pass information from the file to the Asset Application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a Singleton class used by application to read configurations. The you only need to read the file and map info to that class.